# How to cast base class to derived class using Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to cast base object to derived class object using Entity Framework.

I tried to use the copy constructor. The constructor itself does work, but the framework throw errors.

Model classes:

```
public class Member
{
    [Key]
    public string SRU { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }

}

public class Player : Member
{
    public virtual PlayerPosition Position { get; set; }
    public virtual Doctor Doctor { get; set; }
    public virtual HealthIssue HealthIssue { get; set; }

    public Player()
    {

    }
    public Player(Member m)
    {
        SRU = m.SRU;
        Name = m.Name;
        Email = m.Email;
        Address = m.Address;
    }
}
```

My attempt:

```
DatabaseModel db = new DatabaseModel();

var val = db.Members
            .FirstOrDefault(b => b.Name == "Frank");

val = new Player(val);
db.Members.Update(val);

// Save changes in database
db.SaveChanges();
```

I expected to update this entity but it throws error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 
>   'The instance of entity type 'Player' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'SRU'} is already being tracked.
>
> When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

Edit:

I tried it but I change name but type is still same.

```
DatabaseModel db = new DatabaseModel();

var val = db.Members
            .FirstOrDefault(b => b.Name == "Yordan");
db.Entry(val).State = EntityState.Detached;

var val2 = new Player(val);
val2.Name = "Frank";

db.Members.Update(val2);
db.SaveChanges();
```

[image: Sample data]

So i got Member and Player extend Member. In that case I want to cast Member to Player.

Comment: First, this seems to be EF Core, so please update the tags. Second, it sounds like either improper design or XY problem. `val` is either already a `Player` and it's unclear what are you trying to update, or is another `Member` derived type in which case it cannot be converted to `Player`. Please describe what actually are  you trying to do.

Comment: Need to change (extend) Member to Player what normally in programing you use copy constructor but EF not let me do this.

Comment: This is not normal programming because you have chosen to store all `Member`  derived types in a single table ([TPH database inheritance strategy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/inheritance)) with `SRU` being the primary key, so it has be unique. This is what EF error message is trying to tell you.

Comment: Ok, i got it. This database has been done by code first so. Any idea how to redesign it? or how to change `Discriminator`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I approached the subject from the other side and created my own databases and used the generation of context from the existing database.

[image: Diagram]

As a result, I received such a pattern of context

```cs
        public virtual DbSet<Member> Members { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Player> Players { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Senior> Seniors { get; set; }
```

And three generated models

```cs
public partial class Member
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual Player Player { get; set; }
    }
public partial class Player
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Position { get; set; }

        public virtual Member Member { get; set; }
        public virtual Senior Senior { get; set; }
    }
public partial class Senior
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Kin { get; set; }

        public virtual Player Player { get; set; }
    }
```

Is this the only solution to this problem or maybe there are any alternatives or proven constructions. I do not know if this solution is good because I did it intuitively. On the one hand it has sense because all the parts have a common key and the relationship is 1-1, as in inheritance.

Edit:

> summary: I found information from EF Core does not support such solution, and the only option is to use the stored procedure or manual change discriminator if we use one table.

Answer (score 0):

`val` object you are trying to update is new object and it has the same key as one you retrieved from database. As key has to be unique, you can't track two objects with the same key.
Try detaching old object first:

```
DatabaseModel db = new DatabaseModel();
var val = db.Members
        .FirstOrDefault(b => b.Name == "Frank");

var val2 = new Player(val);
db.Entry(val).State = EntityState.Detached;
db.Members.Update(val2);

db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: It stop throw error but still type is same even VS shows i pass `player` type.